# Converting scaled parameters to unscaled parameters in exponential regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonlinear-regression, back-transformation, scaled

I would like to calculate two types of bivariate exponential models on scaled data (therefore both variables are expressed as z-scores):

Model 1:
$$
y=b_{0}*e^{b_{1}x} + \epsilon
$$

Model 2 (is basically model 1 with an additive term b2):
$$
y=b_{2}+b_{0}*e^{b_{1}x} + \epsilon
$$

Now I'm wondering, how can I recover the unscaled parameter estimated from the scaled ones I get from running the models on scaled data? Is there a similar analytical approach to what has been suggested in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361995/how-to-convert-coefficients-from-quadratic-function-from-scaled-to-not-scaled-co)? I tried applying my admittedly basic knowledge of algebra, but could not manage to solve the two equations to a form that would allow me to just read off the respective transformation equation.
Also, in case there is no analytical approach for exponential models, does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I believe I figured out a solution for model 1, by using a natural log transformation to make the model linear. It seems to work, at least if I change the additive error term to a multiplicative error term.

Adapted model 1:

$$
y=b_{0}*e^{b_{1}x} * \epsilon
$$

Taking the natural log does the trick:

$$
\ln(y)= \ln(b_{0})+b_{1}x+ \ln( \epsilon)
$$

When scaling both variables x and y:

$$
x'= \dfrac{x- \overline{x}}{ \sigma_{x}}; y'= \dfrac{y- \overline{y}}{ \sigma_{y}}
$$

and calculating model 1 with the scaled variables, my solution to recover the original unstandardized parameter scale is the following (i.e., scaled parameters are expressed with an apostrophe, e.g. as b'; means are expressed with an overbar; standard deviations are expressed as sigma):

$$
b_{0}=e^{ \ln(b_{0}')* \sigma_{ \ln(y)}+ \overline{ \ln(y)}-b'* \overline{x}* \tfrac{ \sigma_{ \ln(y)}}{ \sigma_{x}}}
$$

$$
b_{1}=b_{1}'* \dfrac{ \sigma_{ \ln(y)}}{ \sigma_{x}}
$$

$$
\epsilon= \epsilon '* \sigma_{ \ln(y)}
$$

If you find an mistake in my solution, please let me know.

However, I still couldn't find a solution to model 2 in my original post, as I can't figure out an algebraic workaround to deal with the additive parameter. Do any experienced mathematicians have an idea how to solve this?